How to use ViewModel with Android Compose?
I use a Composable function that contains a lot of states and methods, so I encapsulate them into a ViewModel. I expect this ViewModel to automatically initialize every time the Composable function is displayed, and to automatically destroy them when the Composable function is destroyed. But in reality, the ViewModel instance is retained in memory, so every time the Composable function is re entered, old data is still used. I have to define an additional init method to reinitialize, but there should be a better way.
class ModifyPointM: ViewModel() {
    val pointName = mutableStateOf("")
    val pointType = mutableStateOf("")
    val pointValue = mutableStateOf(0)
    fun init(){
        pointName.value = ""
        pointType.value = ""
        pointValue.value = 0
    }
    fun changePoint(){
        ...
    }
}

//Use ViewModel in Composable function
@Composable
fun ModifyDialog(onDismiss:()->Unit, modifyPointM: ModifyPointM = viewModel()){
    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        modifyPointM.init()
    }
    ...
}


Please [edit] your question to clearly define when exactly you want the stored data to be reset. On each recomposition? On device reconfigurations like screen rotations? Each time a new instance of the composable is created the first time - or something else? As you can see, the answers so far are mostly poking around guessing.

Your approach of calling init() inside LaunchedEffect(Unit) is reasonable, but there’s a better way to ensure a fresh state for your ViewModel without relying on explicit initialization. Here's a refined solution:
Key Issue:-
The ViewModel is designed to persist its state across configuration changes or composable recompositions. If you want a new ViewModel instance every time the Composable is displayed, you need to explicitly manage the scope of the ViewModel.
Solution: Use a Key to Recreate the ViewModel
You can achieve this by providing a unique key to the viewModel() function. This ensures that the ViewModel is recreated when the key changes.
@Composable
fun ModifyDialog(
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    dialogId: String // Pass a unique key for the dialog instance
) {
    val modifyPointM: ModifyPointM = viewModel(key = dialogId) // ViewModel will recreate for each new key

    // Directly use the ViewModel without needing explicit init
    ...
}


Another Option: Use a Local ViewModel Provider
For cases where you want the ViewModel to have a lifecycle tied directly to the Composable, you can use remember and manage it locally:
@Composable
fun ModifyDialog(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    val modifyPointM = remember { ModifyPointM() } // Scoped to this Composable

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            // Cleanup logic if needed
        }
    }

    // Use the ViewModel
    ...
}


The behavior you're experiencing is because ViewModel instances in Jetpack Compose are scoped to their NavBackStackEntry or the Activity by default. This means they persist across recompositions and even when the Composable is removed and re-added, as long as the same scope is retained.
To address your problem, there are a couple of solutions depending on your use case.
Solution 1: Use remember to initialize the ViewModel
If you want the ViewModel to reset every time the Composable is displayed,
you can manage its initialization using remember and rememberUpdatedState.
This avoids the need for a manual init() call:
@Composable
fun ModifyDialog(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
   val modifyPointM = remember {
       ModifyPointM().apply {
           // Initialize the ViewModel here
           pointName.value = ""
           pointType.value = ""
           pointValue.value = 0
       }
    }

   // Use modifyPointM in your UI
}

This approach creates a new ModifyPointM instance each time ModifyDialog is recomposed and avoids using the default viewModel() scoping.
Solution 2: Pass in ViewModel State Explicitly
Alternatively, if you are using a ViewModel that persists in a larger
scope (e.g., navigation), you can explicitly pass the necessary state as
parameters to the Composable. This ensures that recomposition uses fresh
data:
@Composable
fun ModifyDialog(
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    pointName: String = "",
    pointType: String = "",
    pointValue: Int = 0,
    onPointChange: (String, String, Int) -> Unit
) {
    // Manage state locally or via ViewModel
}

Solution 3: Use rememberSaveable for Local State
If your data doesn't need to persist outside the Composable, use
rememberSaveable for local state management without involving a ViewModel:
@Composable
fun ModifyDialog(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    var pointName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var pointType by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var pointValue by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

    // UI logic here
}

This way, the state is automatically reset when the Composable is removed and re-added.
Solution 4: Create a Scoped ViewModel with key
If you want to reuse viewModel() but with a new instance every time the Composable is displayed, you can provide a unique key:
@Composable
fun ModifyDialog(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    val modifyPointM: ModifyPointM = viewModel(key = 
"ModifyDialog_${UUID.randomUUID()}")
   // This ensures a new ViewModel instance each time
}


If you want to reset state locally: Use rememberSaveable (Solution 3).
If you want to reset the ViewModel state: Use remember for initialization (Solution 1) or a unique key with viewModel() (Solution 4).
If you want to persist state globally: Manage initialization and reuse explicitly (Solution 2).

